# EditText colors and DateDialog text

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, styling

I'm currently developing an android app. I've just discovered something weird and I can't seem to remove it. There is 2 weird things happening:

**First issue:**

I can't seem to figure out why the "**Mon, Jan 25, 2016**" text is at the top of my DateDialog and if it's possible to remove? You can see the image below, to see my DateDialog.
You can also see the styling of the DateDialog below.

**Second issue:**

I have an EditText box and the colors of the two buttons at the buttom of the dialog, can't seem to change color. Which styling elements do I have to add or is there an easy solution for me to fix this??

*Datedialog:*

[image: Weird text at the top of DateDialog]

*EditText box:*

[image: Weird button colors]

*Styling:*

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MenuBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ShadowMenuBar</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
</style>
```

*DateDialog creation code:*

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    Date.setOnClickListener(this);
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            if(view.isShown())
            {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            }
        }
    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the dialog creations ? There shouldn't be a problem with the styling code.

Comment: Hey @brainsandwich I've added the creation of the DateDialog above.

Comment: It might be an important note to add, that the DateDialog opens when clicking on an EditText view.

Comment: @brainsandwich do you have any solution to changing the color of the buttons in the edittext view??